# What is the point of Ruby's @@double_at_variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I rarely use the `@@double_at_variable`, don't even know what to call it. When I dig into gems and os projects I usually come across this variable and it throws me for a loop.

What does it do that the other ruby variables cannot achieve and what is usually the application in projects such as Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double `@` variables are [class variables](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Class_Variables).

That means, there is only one of them **per class** unlike common instance variables (one **per object**)

Comment: Not per class, but per calss hierarchies. That variables are also shared among all class' descendants.

Comment: vderyagin is right, its not really like a static class member

Comment: It's one per class object (classes are objects too)